# Converting Nodejs or Java signature hashing function to PHP

Tags: java, php, node.js, digital-signature, pki

I am trying to create a PKI signature using the private key in PHP.

These are the following rules to create a signature

1. Use the SHA-2 algorithm to generate the hash of the Signature Base String.
2. Sign the hashed value using the private key of the app.
3. Base64-encode the signature value.
   NOTE: Base64 encoding should not include the CRLF (carriage return/line feed) every 72 characters
   which is part of strict Base64 encoding. Instead, the whole Base64 encoded string should be without
   line breaks.
4. Set the string as the value for the signature parameter.

Example of Nodejs code:

```
var signature = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256')
                      .update(baseString)
                      .sign(signWith, 'base64');
```

Java Code

```
String baseString = "Constructed base string";
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("RSA-SHA256");
sig.initSign(privateKey); // Get private key from keystone
sig.update(baseString.getBytes());
byte[] signedData = sig.sign();
String finalStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedData);
```

I am trying to convert this code into PHP,
My base string is correct.

```
// $data = "BaseString";
// $private_key_pem = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://".$path."privateKey.pem",'passphrase');
$hash = hash('sha256', $data);
$result = openssl_sign($hash, $signature, $private_key_pem,'RSA-SHA256');
$signature = base64_encode($signature);
```

Is this correct?
If yes, The API response is "Invalid PKI signature"

Answer (score 1):

I setup two programs in Java and PHP to compare the output (signature = finalStr) and
the verification of the signature. To get a comparable result I hardcoded the RSA keys
in both programs so the code looks like a little bit strange.

**To get shorter key strings I generated 512 bit RSA keys that are unsecure -
use a minimum of 2048 bit keys in production.**

As you can see both programs generate the same signature of:

```
finalStr: NEHC7o+mW34qoTNOwXRQIRfs80s/YhudzX0K4AGlFTeyyJcRhit9f03iw58Ww1Eo3zfkSrrz3411TZheVLHFnQ==
```

and both programs can verify the signature as `true`.

This is the Java code:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MainSo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674669/converting-nodejs-or-java-signature-hashing-function-to-php");

        // keys are sample rsa 512 keys
        String privateKey1 = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
                "MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAqg8Hlhxm7LfqASjF\n" +
                "KMce91anr2ViG/K8GQmk0HPMiw3Lh6DrGDGmsw2jUczwQTyv07qDwWwf+vaEiTdk\n" +
                "jd1JxQIDAQABAkAOGbTtU2mNUyqJ8hF28hu1MnAw8N0TqCrEgLIzvoZFOTqvxPqc\n" +
                "VaCuUs4Fm/J5x8gWLycsRmbBMeecIzvjzXY5AiEAtoZ4WSplvJbEHjiKhW+dRICc\n" +
                "tSTcGaTf0v4vdfQTiGsCIQDug9wLUZDiSttbz2QlA3QthFX+UIu8fE/A/lGEjXnC\n" +
                "jwIgcejRyrPO8jcVBdc7e7MAbvPk2Je8VLS0irTfYbmFRykCIQDCFsbu5vbxTlzm\n" +
                "fwNNI1xc1b1sb3rmbHox4EHRjZaxfQIgEr2r53jmSRlyQfueo4nLZJhTGXdaJN8Z\n" +
                "yoWwFsFqsiA=\n" +
                "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
        String publicKey1 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKoPB5YcZuy36gEoxSjHHvdWp69lYhvy\n" +
                "vBkJpNBzzIsNy4eg6xgxprMNo1HM8EE8r9O6g8FsH/r2hIk3ZI3dScUCAwEAAQ==\n" +
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        // rsa key generation
        // Remove markers and new line characters in private key
        String realPrivateKey = privateKey1.replaceAll("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll("\n", "");
        byte[] priKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(realPrivateKey);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec specPri = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(priKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(specPri);
        // Remove markers and new line characters in public key
        String realPublicKey = publicKey1.replaceAll("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll("\n", "");
        byte[] pubKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(realPublicKey);
        X509EncodedKeySpec specPub = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKey);
        PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(specPub);

        String baseString = "Constructed base string";

        //Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("RSA-SHA256");
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initSign(privateKey); // Get private key from keystone
        sig.update(baseString.getBytes());
        byte[] signedData = sig.sign();
        String finalStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedData);
        System.out.println("finalStr: " + finalStr);

        // verify signature
        byte[] signedDataVerify = Base64.getDecoder().decode(finalStr);
        Signature sigVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sigVerify.initVerify(publicKey);
        sigVerify.update(baseString.getBytes());
        boolean verified = sigVerify.verify(signedDataVerify);
        System.out.println("signature verified: " + verified);
    }
}
```

and here is the PHP-code:

```
<?php
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674669/converting-nodejs-or-java-signature-hashing-function-to-php
$data = 'Constructed base string';

// sample 512 rsa keys
$privateKey1 = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" .
        "MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAqg8Hlhxm7LfqASjF\n" .
        "KMce91anr2ViG/K8GQmk0HPMiw3Lh6DrGDGmsw2jUczwQTyv07qDwWwf+vaEiTdk\n" .
        "jd1JxQIDAQABAkAOGbTtU2mNUyqJ8hF28hu1MnAw8N0TqCrEgLIzvoZFOTqvxPqc\n" .
        "VaCuUs4Fm/J5x8gWLycsRmbBMeecIzvjzXY5AiEAtoZ4WSplvJbEHjiKhW+dRICc\n" .
        "tSTcGaTf0v4vdfQTiGsCIQDug9wLUZDiSttbz2QlA3QthFX+UIu8fE/A/lGEjXnC\n" .
        "jwIgcejRyrPO8jcVBdc7e7MAbvPk2Je8VLS0irTfYbmFRykCIQDCFsbu5vbxTlzm\n" .
        "fwNNI1xc1b1sb3rmbHox4EHRjZaxfQIgEr2r53jmSRlyQfueo4nLZJhTGXdaJN8Z\n" .
        "yoWwFsFqsiA=\n" .
        "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

$publicKey1 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" .
        "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAKoPB5YcZuy36gEoxSjHHvdWp69lYhvy\n" .
        "vBkJpNBzzIsNy4eg6xgxprMNo1HM8EE8r9O6g8FsH/r2hIk3ZI3dScUCAwEAAQ==\n" .
        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private ($privateKey1);
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($publicKey1);

// create the signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
echo 'finalStr (Base64):' . PHP_EOL . base64_encode($signature) . PHP_EOL;

// verify signature
$result = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $publicKey, "sha256WithRSAEncryption");
echo 'verified (0=false, 1=true): ' . $result;
?>
```

Comment: TY, the result I want is match with https://8gwifi.org/rsasignverifyfunctions.jsp